# How to append Bool value of a struct in Swift

Tags: swift, struct, boolean, append

So, I'm coding in Swift and I've made a struct called User. It has four categories of characteristics- name, email, number of followers, and activity status. I am able to append values of the variables of the structs I create without issue, so long as they are Strings or Ints, Dicts etc. It won't let me append the value of the Bool. I initially set it to 'true', but I'd like to append it to being 'false' after initializing it. I'm getting the error message: "Value of type 'Bool' has no member 'append'". I get that I'm not allowed to append it the same way as I can with say User.name.append("Tim"), but what I don't get is how I actually *can* append it. Google was unhelpful,searching in SO also yielded nothing of note, and Apple documentation on Structs shows them setting similar values in their explanation at the beginning using Strings and Bools and appending the Strings but not appending the Bools. I can't imagine it not being possible as things change all the time from true to false status, depending on the situation. If I remove the line below, it compiles fine.

userTwo.isAcctive.append(false) is where my error is, for clarity.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
struct User {
  let name: String
  let email: String?
  var followers: Int
  var isActive: Bool

  init(name: String, email: String, followers: Int, isActive: Bool){
    self.name = name
    self.email = email
    self.followers = followers
    self.isActive = isActive
  }

  func logStatus(){
    if isActive == true{
    print("\(name) is working hard.")
    } else {
      print("\(name) has left the earth.")
    }
  }
}

var userOne = User(name: "Richard", email:("") , followers: 0, isActive: false)

var userTwo = User(name: "Elon", email:("elon@tesla.com") , followers: 2100, isActive: true)
print(userTwo.isActive)
userTwo.isActive.append(false)

userOne.logStatus()
userTwo.logStatus()
```

Comment: You don't want to 'append' it - you want to change it. Just say `userTwo.isActive = false` will do the job. There is no history attached to primitive types.

Comment: Its not an array to use append function. Its like a primitive element with TRUE OR FALSE value. Just use userTwo.isActive = false. ``.append`` is used for arrays , strings etc.

Comment: This makes sense. I can move forward now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appending is to add a new element to an array. I think you want to change isActive property. You can do this by:

```
var userTwo = User(name: "Elon", email:("elon@tesla.com") , followers: 2100, isActive: true)
userTwo.isActive = false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
struct User {
    var name :String
    var email :String?
    var followers :Int
    var isActive :Bool
    
    
        init(name: String, email: String?, followers: Int, isActive: Bool){
        self.name = name
        self.email = email!
        self.followers = followers
        self.isActive = isActive
  }
  
  func logStatus() {
      if isActive == true {
          print("\(name) is working hard")
      }
      else {
          print("\(name) has left earth")
      }
  }
}

let userOne = User(name: "Richard", email:("richard@virgin"), followers: 0, isActive: false)
userOne.logStatus()
    
    print("\nDiagnostic code (i.e., Challenge Hint):")
    var musk = User(name: "Elon", email: "elon@tesla.com", followers: 2001, isActive: true)
    musk.logStatus()
    print("Contacting \(musk.name) on \(musk.email!) ...")
    print("\(musk.name) has \(musk.followers) followers")
    
    musk.isActive = false
    musk.logStatus()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the struct below the creation of itself, you cant create an struct and initialize itself inside it.

```swift
struct User {
  var name: String
  var email: String?
  var followers: Int
  var isActive: Bool
        
  func logStatus() {
    if isActive {
      print(name + " is working hard")
    } else {
      print(name+" has left earth")
    }
  }
}

// Initialise a User struct here
let richard = User(name: "Richard", email: "richard@tesla.com", followers: 0, isActive: false)
richard.logStatus()

// Diagnostic code - do not change this code
print("\nDiagnostic code (i.e., Challenge Hint):")
var musk = User(name: "Elon", email: "elon@tesla.com", followers: 2001, isActive: true)
musk.logStatus()
print("Contacting \(musk.name) on \(musk.email!) ...")
print("\(musk.name) has \(musk.followers) followers")
// sometime later
musk.isActive = false
musk.logStatus()
```